# corrupted openSSL, website down can't SSH, yum, rpm etc

Tags: centos, php, openssl

I was trying to install uTorrent on my PHP site and mid-process I was kicked out of SSH and the website went down.

libssl.so.1.0.0 and libcrypto.so.1.0.0 were required for uTorrent so to downgrade, I did the following:

```
wget https://www.openssl.org/source/openssl-1.0.0r.tar.gz
cd openssl-1.0.0r
./config shared && make
```

Installation went fine and it replaced my previous version 1.0.1e. But when I ldd, the list shows "No version could be found" for libssl.so.1.0.0 and libcrypto.so.1.0.0. I proceeded to delete both of them from my server hoping to revert the changes and immediately got kicked out of SSH and the site went down.

Now I can't connect via SSH, only way is via KVM provided by my host. All commands ie. `yum rpm wget` etc. returns the following error:

```
error while loading shared libraries libcrypto.so.10: file too short
```

My server is unmanaged, therefore I don't think I have the option of manually reinstalling openSSL's packages on a USB...

Comment: You have thoroughly broken your installation. The easiest path to recovery is to reinstall the operating system - and next time, don't even _think_ about compiling OpenSSL yourself.

Comment: I agree with Michael.  That said, you _might_ get back into a less-than-broken state by using `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}:/path/to/your/new/openssl/install/lib` and see if your commands don't error.   Maybe then you can at least rsync your critical data to another server.  That will probably fail.  If you can start rsyncd (native, not ssh) on another server, you can rsync your data to it.  Native rsync does not require openssl libs.

Answer (score 3):

If you have no way of getting a physical media attached to the server, then you need to get the server wiped and reinstalled. Since you managed to corrupt all cryptography libraries in the OS, you need to replace them with correct versions from physical media.

However, the recovery method above requires quite extensive knowledge on how your Linux distribution's packages are managed.

Always follow this guideline: Always use compiled packages for your distribution and version and never compile anything yourself. This saves you from a lot of trouble.

Answer (score 3):

This trick helped a colleague who did something similar with another critical package.

If your KVM access allows to paste from your clipboard then you *could* copy over `libssl.so.10` & `libcrypto.so.10` from a known working installation. To prevent your terminal getting confused, Base64-encode the files first.

Something like this on a known good system:

```
$ base64 </usr/lib64/libssl.so.10
<copy the output>
```

Then on the broken system:

```
$ base64 -d <<EOF >/usr/lib64/libssl.so.10
<paste in the output from above>
EOF
```

(Repeat for `libcrypto.so.10` and any other file)

If that gets things working then reinstall the OS SSL package(s), probably forcing them along the way as the package manager will think they're already installed.

Comment: This could work, but I suspect the user will find himself unable to do it because of the limits of the KVM.